# Parse data with "count" from xml into table html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I know this topic is old. I am learning and trying to parse, but don't know how to do it in my case. Could you guys show me the way to do it or better help me with one or two values?

```
<Metainformation>
    <cash>ABC XYZ</cash>
    <Doctor>Dr. Peter Smith</Doctor>
    <DoctorID>12345678</DoctorID>
    <Quartal>Q22004</Quartal>
    <Checkdate>20040404123000</Checkdate>
</Metainformation>
<Patientlist>
    <Normal_Patient>
        <Unchanged count="123"/>
        <New count="3"/>
        <Closed count="2"/>
        <InTest count="4"/>
    </Normal_Patient>
    <Special_Patient>
        <Special_Quantity count="8" />
    </Special_Patient>
    <Notfound_Patient>
        <ABC_available count="9" />
        <DEF_available count="7" />
    </Notfound_Patient> 
    <Total old="125" new="126"/>
</Patientlist>
```

My table is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/n9ygoL52/

Answer (score 1):

ok, lets assume that you have a file called infos.xml in the same directory where html exist.

this mode that i will show you, requires to set ids for each of td. For example

```
<td>Cash</td>
<td id="cash"> </td>

<td>Doctor</td>
<td id="doctor"> </td>

<td>Quartal</td>
<td id="quartal"> </td>
```

the javascript that i use...

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "infos.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

console.log(xhttp);


function myFunction(xml) {

    var cash = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("cash").innerHTML =
    cash.getElementsByTagName("cash")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var doctor = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("doctor").innerHTML =
    doctor.getElementsByTagName("Doctor")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var quartal = xml.responseXML;
    document.getElementById("quartal").innerHTML =
    quartal.getElementsByTagName("Quartal")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

with the same way you can add all td of table. But it will much better if you use a loop to iterate the table and xml respectively

vote if it helps

**An update**

with this way i take the count...

```
var unchanged = xml.responseXML;

    var attrone= unchanged.getElementsByTagName('Unchanged');

    var c = 0;

    for(var i in attrone){

        if(c == attrone.length) break;

        c++;    
        document.getElementById('unchanged').innerHTML=attrone[i].getAttribute('count');

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot Jordan. I upvoted your solution, but my question was also about the data with `count ` (for example, from `<Unchanged count="123"/>`). How can I parse `123` into my table?

Comment: looking for this. See that you have error in your xml. The </Metainformation> must go to the end of file. In Total add a slash at the close tag :)

Comment: thanks, you are right. I add `/` into Total already. But I don't think </Metainformation> should be at the end. I think this xml data consists of two parts: `Metainformation` and `Patientlist`. Btw, could you tell me the way to value from `count`?

Comment: i said that about MetaInformation because in browser console shows me an error. I update...

Comment: thanks for your update. I have not checked with that. I have just checked `<id="cash">` but it did not work for me. I guess problem here is `if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)`. Could you explain to me about this command?

Comment: this is the status and the state of the response of the XML. called response codes. Here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp explains... 

readyState  The status of the XMLHttpRequest
0: request not initialized
1: server connection established
2: request received
3: processing request
4: request finished and response is ready

and status  200: OK
404: Page not found

so we tell. If the staty and state are 4 and ok, continue

Comment: <td id="cash"> </td> not <id="cash">

Comment: ok, thanks for your explaination. Sorry, I wrote so short. Actually i used `<td id="cash"> </td>`  but it did not work. I do not know where problem is :(. I put .xml data in the same folder already.

Comment: i still belive  that the Metainformation must be in the end of xml file. Test your xml here http://www.xmlvalidation.com ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141645/discussion-between-gnase-and-jordan-georgiadis).